# Return custom user data MVC5 ASP.NET identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I've create a new project and converted my code to use and integer ID instead of a GUID following this guide:

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity#mvcupdate3

Now I want to add some custom fields for my users, something like FirstName.

My RegisterViewModel:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

This works and my First name is persisted to the database.  My problem is I can't retrieve it and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

This is my IdentityModels.cs

```
// You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim> 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FirstName", this.FirstName));
        return userIdentity;
    }
}


public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim> 
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}

public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> {  }
public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }

public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRole() { }
    public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
}

public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<CustomRole, int, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

`user.FirstName` is always null.

Thanks

Comment: show how you are trying to access `user.FirstName`?

Comment: In the GenerateUserIdentityAsync method:

    var user = await manager.FindByEmailAsync(userIdentity.Name);
    userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("FirstName", user.FirstName));

Comment: Are you sure `user.FirstName` is null, and `user` is not null? If you load whole user from database and FirstName is stored in that database, there should be no problem with this. Show sample code where you load user from database.

Comment: Ugh, you're right.  While testing I created two users, one had a FirstName value and the other didn't.  I was testing with the wrong user!  I'm clearly not very bright.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My code did work I was just being dumb.  Really, really dumb.  Thanks to Mateusz for confirming my code should work.